# Update Play Framework (Java) from 2.7.x to 2.8.x. leads to sbt error while compiling (only with sbt 1.x)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I try to update Play Framework (Java) from 2.7.x to 2.8.x. I followed the migration guide (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Migration28).

Changing `sbt.version=0.13.15` to `sbt.version=1.3.10` in file `project/build.properties`
leads to the error.

With `sbt.version=0.13.15` it's working, but the guide says:

> Although Play 2.8 still supports sbt 0.13, we recommend that you use
> sbt 1. This new version is supported and actively maintained

I also tried to delete the folders .ivy2, .cache and .sbt in my home folder.

While `sbt clean compile` comes the following error:

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          org.foundweekends.giter8:sbt-giter8-scaffold:0.7.1 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.foundweekends.giter8:sbt-giter8-scaffold;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.7.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/foundweekends/giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold_2.12_1.0/0.7.1/sbt-giter8-scaffold-0.7.1.pom
[error]   not found: /home/user1/.ivy2/local/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.7.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.7.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.7.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:247)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$35(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:216)
[error]         at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:216)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:102)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:129)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:2950)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.foundweekends.giter8:sbt-giter8-scaffold;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.7.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/foundweekends/giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold_2.12_1.0/0.7.1/sbt-giter8-scaffold-0.7.1.pom
[error]   not found: /home/user1/.ivy2/local/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.7.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.7.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.foundweekends.giter8/sbt-giter8-scaffold/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.7.1/ivys/ivy.xml
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Additional info: I upgraded it before from 2.5.15 to 2.6.0 to 2.7.0 without changing the sbt version. The same error also appears in Play Framework 2.7.0.

Has anyone solved these issues successfully in the past?

Comment: Just remove the _sbt-giter8-scaffold_ plugin from `plugins.sbt`, you don't need it anymore. Or update it to a more recent version.

Comment: @Gaël J Thank you. I solved it in between by the ugliest way. I created a new project wit "sbt new ..." and then I copied my sources in the new project folder and changed the config files.